# Running django with a sqlite in memory database

Tags: django, sqlite, testing, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework for my acceptance testing.

To start the django server I run the `python manage.py runserver` command from the RobotFramework. After that, I call `python manage.py migrate`. But the tests are slow because is not using an in-memory database.

I tried creating a new setting file called testing and I an using the following configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
}
```

and setting the enviroment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE at runtime with this config.

I run a migrate followed by a runserver but the database does not exist. I can't figure out why. If I use a physical database it works.

I tried to check how the Django TestCase works to run and create the database but I could not find it.

Comment: In-memory databases never exist on disk.

Comment: I know. But django tells that the tables were not found so it doesn't works.

Comment: I think that migrate and runserver are in different process so they are not using the same db.

Comment: I found that there are some utilities to set the enviroment and the database but I don't know how the django DiscoverRunner uses the webserver. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#testing-utilities I am getting closer

Answer (score 1):

I try to simulate `make migrate` before running test cases by calling `execute_from_command_line()` manually.

So the command I choose is: (removing `poetry run` if you don't use poetry).

```sh
poetry run ./manage.py test --settings=myproject.settings_test
```

I put this command into `GNUMakefile` to allow me use `make test`.

Then inside `myproject/settings_test.py`:

```py
from .settings import *

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '127.0.0.1', ]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
}

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(['./manage.py', 'migrate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `django.db.connection.creation.create_test_db` function [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#testing-utilities) at the start of your tests and then call `django.db.connection.creation.destroy_test_db` after completing your tests.